# How do I identify Ubuntu VM is running in which cloud (VMware, AWS, Google) from Ubuntu CLI?

Tags: command-line, virtualization, cloud

I need identify Ubuntu VM is running in which cloud (VMware, AWS, Google) from Ubuntu CLI?